# can plsql function return object

Tags: oracle, plsql

i have encountered a problem while writing the following code:

```
create or replace function getashish(dept varchar2) return emp3 as

emp5 emp3;

str varchar2(300);

begin

str := 'select e.last_name,l.city,e.salary from employees e join departments d 

on e.department_id = d.department_id join locations l on d.location_id=l.location_id where 

d.department_name = :dept';

execute immediate str bulk collect into emp5  using dept;

end;
```

emp 3 is table of an object as defined below:

```
create or replace type emp1 as object (lname varchar2(10),city varchar2(10),sal number(10));

create or replace type emp3 as table of emp1;
```

i am getting the following error while executing the function: SQL Error:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got -
```

thank you for your anticipated help and support.

Comment: yes you can return objects, but you use it in SQL or PL/SQL to invoke, can you please show us that snippet?

Comment: yes select getashish('IT') from dual;

Comment: select * from table(getashish('IT'));

Comment: Than k you i had gone a bit fast on your answer its working

Answer (score 2):

Please try the below, (added `emp1()` to your select query inside function and returned `emp5`)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getashish(
    dept VARCHAR2)
  RETURN emp3
AS
  emp5 emp3 := emp3();
  str VARCHAR2(300);
BEGIN
  str := 'select emp1(e.last_name,l.city,e.salary) from employees e join departments d 
on e.department_id = d.department_id join locations l on d.location_id=l.location_id where 
d.department_name = :dept';
  EXECUTE immediate str bulk collect INTO emp5 USING dept;
  RETURN emp5;
END;
/
```

**and the caller block**

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE( CAST(getashish('IT') AS emp3))
UNION
SELECT * FROM TABLE( CAST(getashish('FINANCE') AS emp3));
```

the function returns a Table, and hence cant be used in `SELECT` clause, since it is supposed to return one row only, if have to be used in `SELECT`. Hope you got the concept!

**EDIT:** Whatever I did!

```
create table employees 
(last_name varchar2(10),salary number,department_id varchar2(10));

create table locations
(location_id varchar2(10),city varchar2(10));
drop table employees;

create table departments
(department_id varchar2(10),location_id varchar2(10),department_name varchar2(10));

insert into employees values ('ASHISH',6000000,'D1');
insert into employees values ('MAHESH',5000000,'D2');

insert into departments values('D1','L1','IT');
insert into departments values('D2','L2','FINANCE');

insert into locations values('L1','Gurgoan');
insert into locations values('L2','Chennai');

commit;

create or replace type emp1 as object (lname varchar2(10),city varchar2(10),sal number(10));
/

create or replace type emp3 as table of emp1;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getashish(
    dept VARCHAR2)
  RETURN emp3
AS
  emp5 emp3 := emp3();
  str VARCHAR2(300);
BEGIN
  str := 'select emp1(e.last_name,l.city,e.salary) from employees e join departments d 
on e.department_id = d.department_id join locations l on d.location_id=l.location_id where 
d.department_name = :dept';
  EXECUTE immediate str bulk collect INTO emp5 USING dept;
  RETURN emp5;
END;
/

SELECT * FROM TABLE( CAST(getashish('IT') AS emp3))
UNION
SELECT * FROM TABLE( CAST(getashish('FINANCE') AS emp3));

SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE( CAST(getashish('IT') AS emp3))
  2  UNION
  3  SELECT * FROM TABLE( CAST(getashish('FINANCE') AS emp3));

LNAME      CITY              SAL
---------- ---------- ----------
ASHISH     Gurgoan       6000000
MAHESH     Chennai       5000000
```

Comment: its not a snippet problem the error is due to data types used in function SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got -
ORA-06512: at "HR.GETASHISH", line 8

Comment: Error starting at line 2 in command:
SELECT * FROM
TABLE( CAST(getashish('IT') as emp3))
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got -
ORA-06512: at "HR.GETASHISH", line 8 . The error remains the same its not working we need to use method to invoke this , I think

Comment: Please read my answer. You should have been missing something.

Answer (score 1):

try declaring emp5 as a datatype of emp1.

```
emp5 emp1 := emp1();
```